# How to build a delete button to remove a character from the TextField every time delete button is clicked?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, javafx-8

JavaFX TextField

How to build a delete button (can detect which one of the TextField is actived) and remove a character from the TextField every time delete button is clicked?

(Sorry it wasn't clear, here is more explanation)
I have three TextField (as list below), when cursor is at one of the TextField say at tf1, when I click btnDelete Button, one character can be deleted from ft1 (btnDelete Button should work the same way as delete from computer keyboard).

```
@FXML
TextField tf1;
@FXML
TextField tf2;
@FXML
TextField tf3;

@FXML
public void btnDelete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "which one of the `TextField` is activated"? Can you post some code to show how you have things set up, and what you have tried?

Comment: I think he has for example 3 TextFields and one Delete Button. His problem is maybe the lost focus of last edited TextField when Button is pressed. So he Looks for a way to store the last focused TextField and remove Char from that end? Existing Code would help :) as James_D stated

Comment: Thanks James_D and Inge, I have added more explanation.

Comment: note that this site is not for doing _your_ homework ;-) That snippet obviously doesn't do anything, so how could there be a problem? Start with one field, make the handler do something (like f.i. writing out a string) Then learn how to delete a char in the field via a button, then put that code into the handler. Then add the other two textfields and find out how to target the delete to any of them. In the process, come back with a SSCCE that demonstrates a concrete problem (should you still have any :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help kleopatra,  focusedProperty is exactly what i need, I should post my question in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for your problem is to use focusedProperty to save , 
when newValue is true, on a generic TextField txt the TextField focused ...
view this example code:

```
@FXML
TextField tf1;
@FXML
TextField tf2;
@FXML
TextField tf3;

TextField txt;

@FXML
public void btnDelete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    txt.setText( txt.getText().substring(0, txt.getText().length()-1));
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {   

    tf1.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue){
                txt=tf1;
            }
        }
    });

    tf2.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue){
                txt=tf2;
            }
        }
    });

    tf3.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue){
                txt=tf3;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: focusedProperty is exactly what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
textfield.setText(textfield.getText(0, textfield.getLength()-1));
```

Comment: Please explain what the above mentioned code is doing. It would be helpful for everybody who's looking for an answer.

Comment: The code in this answer removes the last character of a TextField (named textfield)